# How to list unpaired Bluetooth Devices in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, bluetooth, windows-phone-8.1, hardware

I'm a total newbie on WP and I want to build an App that look for unpaired BT devices whenever they come in range.

So far I figured out that there is only one way to have unpaired BT devices and that's AppToApp way. But I have two questions:

1) Is there another way to doing that?
2) We have some external antennas to look for (the kind of antennas that we plus to our PC) and I don't know if I can run an app on an antenna or not!

Should I tell my boss to purchase lots of WP devices and stick them everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API for pairing Bluetooth devices in Windows Phone.  You can detect which devices are already paired with the phone and use those, but you can't find unpaired devices.